# min() window function in vertica not working properly - returns different values for same window

Tags: sql, window-functions, vertica

I am using vertica and using the min() window function, over a window. However, the function seem to work fine for some of the windows but for some windows, it is returning different min values in the same window. Is there anything that I am overlooking

```
 select visid_high, visid_low, visit_num, date_time, visit_page_num,
         min(visit_page_num) over (partition by visid_high , visid_low , visit_num order by date_time)  as min_hotelinfo
from prd_omniture_hit_data_all  where pagename='Hotel Info - Home' and date(Date_time)='2016-06-19' order by visid_high, visid_low, visit_num, date_time
```

This works fine for some windows and returns result as below

```
visid_high  visid_low   visit_num   date_time   visit_page_num  min_hotelinfo
1000025785676989783 3541599610445607061 1   6/19/2016 8:54  2   2
1000025785676989783 3541599610445607061 1   6/19/2016 8:55  4   2
1000025785676989783 3541599610445607061 1   6/19/2016 8:55  5   2

visid_high  visid_low   visit_num   date_time   visit_page_num  min_hotelinfo
1000334043872452151 13928857828543794490    1   6/19/2016 14:56 2   2
1000334043872452151 13928857828543794490    1   6/19/2016 14:57 6   2
1000334043872452151 13928857828543794490    1   6/19/2016 14:57 7   2
1000334043872452151 13928857828543794490    2   6/19/2016 16:09 2   2
10006241273945967252    17961652664059791311    1   6/19/2016 20:09 2   2
10006241273945967252    17961652664059791311    1   6/19/2016 20:09 4   2
10006241273945967252    17961652664059791311    1   6/19/2016 20:10 8   2
```

However, for some windows, it is not functioning properly

```
visid_high  visid_low   visit_num   date_time   visit_page_num  min_hotelinfo
10007599756616641840    269931436307846555  2   6/19/2016 19:51 2   2
10007599756616641840    269931436307846555  2   6/19/2016 19:52 3   2
10007599756616641840    269931436307846555  2   6/19/2016 19:52 5   2
10007599756616641840    269931436307846555  2   6/19/2016 19:53 7   2
10007599756616641840    269931436307846555  2   6/19/2016 19:53 9   2
10007599756616641840    269931436307846555  2   6/19/2016 19:53 10  **10**

10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:03  5   5
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:03  7   **5**
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:09  26  **26**
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:12  28  26
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:13  30  26
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:14  32  26
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:15  36  26
10009683770139214971    14890994612952617462    2   6/19/2016 8:17  40  26


visid_high  visid_low   visit_num   date_time   visit_page_num  min_hotelinfo
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 7:22  4   4
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 7:24  5   4
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 7:24  8   4
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 7:24  7   4
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 7:24  6   **4**
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 8:04  16  **16**
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 8:06  20  16
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 8:06  25  16
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 8:07  28  16
10012413883034897266    8201606845758098188 1   6/19/2016 8:07  30  16
```

Comment: Which exact version of Vertica are you running? `select version();`

Comment: @ woot Vertica Analytic Database v7.2.3-0

Comment: Why the `order by` in the window definition? I fail so see why you would need an `order by` to get the minimum. Usually an `order by` in an aggregate used as a window function turns that into a "running aggregate". Does it work as you expect it to work when you remove the `order by`?

Answer (score 1):

Order the window so that the partitions group together properly.

```
select visid_high, visid_low, visit_num, date_time, visit_page_num,
       min(visit_page_num) over 
         (partition by visid_high, visid_low, visit_num 
          order by visid_high, visid_low, visit_num) as min_hotelinfo
from prd_omniture_hit_data_all  
where pagename = 'Hotel Info - Home' 
and date(Date_time) = '2016-06-19' 
order by visid_high, visid_low, visit_num, date_time
```

Also, may not want to cast Date_time that way. Better to avoid casting and functions on predicates so the database can optimize better (not that it will, but you give it more opportunity).

```
where Date_time >= '2016-06-19' and Date_time < '2016-06-20'
```